# Reverse proxy nginx apache SSL

Tags: apache, nginx, ssl, proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a website running on Apache on port 8443 (http).. and I want to use Nginx as a reverse proxy
to access Apache, but on https with a self-signed certificate.
I've tried various ways, but nothing is working...

When I access it directly through port 8443 without going through Nginx, it works fine.
However, when I try to access it via https://example.com... I get ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT.

Here's my configuration file (/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf):

```
server {
    listen       443 ssl http2;
    server_name  www.example.com;

    ssl_client_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/www.example.com.pem;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/www.example.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/www.example.com.key;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
    ssl_session_timeout 10m;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    
    location / {
        index  index.html index.htm index.php;
        proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:8443;
    }
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
    
    location ~ \.php$ {
        proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:8443;
    }
}
```